# CSS: Make child div width auto to content in it, not the full parent width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some problems with my css. Sorry about the title, i'm not too sure how to explain it in a few words, but here it is. This is the problem i'm having. I have a wrapper parent div, and that is aligned to the center of the page. Inside that div I have another div, and that div contains pictures in it. The problem is I have the child div set to width:auto, and the width is always the full length of the parent div. What I want is it to auto scale to be just as big as the content inside it, so I can center it within the parent div. Here is a picture of what I mean.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhntF.png)

The grey part is my parent div, wrapper, and the red part is my child div, gameswrapper. I want gameswrapper to be the same size as the game pictures in it

Here is my css

```
#wrapper {
background: #ddd;
width: 70%;
max-width: 70%;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold';
}
#gamesdisplay {
    display:block;
}
#searchdisplay {
    display:block;
}
.artwork {
margin: 6px;
width: 150px;
height: 230px;  
background: #666;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this is my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="gamesdisplay" style="overflow:auto; width:auto; background:red;">
<a href=''><div class="artwork" style="background: url('')"></div></a>
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

https://jsbin.com/tohuluzehu/edit?html,css,output

Simply use inline-block as the display mode of the child... this will take the width expanding behaviour of the div away :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting `#wrapper` to have `text-align: center` and giving `#gamesdisplay` the dipslay type of `inline-block`.

Here's the CSS (inc your original CSS):

```
#wrapper {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold';
  text-align: center;
}
#gamesdisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#searchdisplay {
  display:block;
}
```

and here's a working example on codepen:

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/grvmzj

Comment: That works, but unfortunately when you get to the bottom, if there's less images on the last line, they'll be aligned to the center like this http://prntscr.com/aqteob Is there any way to align them to the center, but still on the left side?

Comment: @blackhawk338 could you amend your original question with the styles you are applying to the images?

Comment: @blackhawk338 you can just add `float: left` to `.artwork` and you get what you're looking for:

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/grvmzj

Comment: Unfortunately when you put float: left to .artwork, they go back to bnot being centered http://prntscr.com/aqtmm7

Comment: @blackhawk338 i think there is more styling interfering. if you see here: 

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/grvmzj

you can see only two `.artwork`'s are in the markup and is still centered.